# Orleans When Use RedisGrainStorage for "PubSubStore" throw GrainReferenceNotBoundException

Tags: c#, orleans

Orleans Blazor Server Sample,it work well.
https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/tree/main/samples/Blazor/BlazorServer

I just use Redis Persistence replace memory storage

```
    <PackageReference Include="Orleans.Persistence.Redis" Version="3.1.1" />
```

```cs
await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseOrleans(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseLocalhostClustering();
        //builder.AddMemoryGrainStorageAsDefault();
        builder.AddRedisGrainStorageAsDefault((options) =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = redisConnection;
            options.UseJson          = true;
            options.DatabaseNumber   = 1;
        });

        builder.AddSimpleMessageStreamProvider("SMS");
        //builder.AddMemoryGrainStorage("PubSubStore");
        builder.AddRedisGrainStorage("PubSubStore", options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = redisConnection;
            options.UseJson          = true;
            options.DatabaseNumber   = 2;
        });
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .RunConsoleAsync();
```

It work well when first build and run. Redis database created datas.
But when runing again it thrown exception  when calling:

```cs
public Task<StreamSubscriptionHandle<TodoNotification>> SubscribeAsync(Guid ownerKey, Func<TodoNotification, Task> action) =>
            client.GetStreamProvider("SMS")
                .GetStream<TodoNotification>(ownerKey, nameof(ITodoGrain))
                .SubscribeAsync(new TodoItemObserver(logger, action));
```

the exception is

```
GrainReferenceNotBoundException: Attempted to use a GrainReference which has not been bound to the runtime: GrainReference:*grn/BlazorServer.TodoGrain/4794564e-4c87-4674-8722-f87f20559abe-0x3CAFC40C. Use the IGrainFactory.BindGrainReference method to bind this reference to the runtime.
```

my question is  how could I fix this exception? Thanks.